# How to use TableRowInkWell inside Table in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Does anyone create a table with TableRowInkWell?

I wanted a table with clickable row on the left and unclickable row on the right.

Are there any example for creating a nice table?

Comment: This is confusing; do you mean you want a two-column table with a clickable column on the left and unclickable column on the right?
Also, for this you might be better off just having an InkWell in each element of the first column....

Answer (score 4):

You can only use `TableRowInkWell` inside the `TableRow` or `TableCell`

for example:

```
Table(
  border: TableBorder.all(),
  children: [
    TableRow(children: [
    ///Like this one*******
      TableRowInkWell(
          onTap: (){},
        child: Column(children: [
          Icon(
            Icons.account_box,
            size: iconSize,
          ),
          Text('My Account'),
        ]),
      ),
      Column(children: [
        Icon(
          Icons.settings,
          size: iconSize,
        ),
        Text('Settings')
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
)
```