# Handle tap in Flutter TableRow

Tags: flutter, flutter-table

I need to make the TableRow clickable and navigate to other screen but I cannot wrap TableRow with GestureDetector or Inkwell. How can I make the TableRow clickable. I have implemented as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < menuList.length; i++)
              TableRow(children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                Text((i + 1).toString()),
                Text(menuList[i].name),
                Text(menuList[i].price.toString()),
                Text(menuList[i].maxQty.toString()),
                menuList[i].status == 0
                    ? Text(
                        menuList[i].foodStatus,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                      )
                    : YourListViewItem(
                        id: menuList[i].id,
                        index: menuList[i].status,
                      ),
              ]),
```

Comment: Full code will be helpful....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do this,

You can use [DataTable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html) instead of **Table** widget, it will definitely meet your need.

> In **DataRow** there is a property named **onSelectChanged**, This is
> exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Not for the whole row, but for the individual cells in a row you can use TableRowInkWell. TableRowInkWell goes inside a TableRow itself, wrapping a child. Here is the answer, with credit to SoloWofl93: [How to use TableRowInkWell inside Table in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49677189/how-to-use-tablerowinkwell-inside-table-in-flutter)

```
Table(
  border: TableBorder.all(),
  children: [
    TableRow(children: [
     
      // HERE IT IS...
      TableRowInkWell(
        onTap: (){},
        child: Column(children: [
          Icon(
            Icons.account_box,
            size: iconSize,
          ),
          Text('My Account'),
        ]),
      ),
     
      Column(children: [
        Icon(
          Icons.settings,
          size: iconSize,
        ),
        Text('Settings')
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28101496)

Comment: Answer enhanced, please re-review.

Answer (score -2):

It is not possible to achieve this since `TableRow` is not a widget and hence it can't be wrapped in other widgets like `InkWell`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63249132/16823675) is the best option you have for now.

One of the possible solutions you can try is adding an `InkWell` of exactly the same size on top of the target `TableRow` using a stack widget. But that would be difficult to implement and it is not a clean way of doing it.

Or you can keep an `InkWell` in each cell in the table where you need to handle taps, which will be redundant

There is a possible solution in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61085706/16823675). I haven't tried it though.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).